# how to overwrite csv file opened again on MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

the issue is that writing csv file that was opened already
the environment is Visual 6.0 C++ (MFC)
time variable is executing time

```
 int time = 1 ;
  BOOL  blNewXls = FALSE;
  _Application objApp;
  _Workbook objBook;
  Workbooks objBooks;
  Worksheets objSheets;
  _Worksheet objSheet;
  Range objRange;
  LPDISPATCH lpDisp;          



BOOL TestView::SaveTrxGeneration1ExcelFile(CString destFileName, MYSQL_ROW row, int num_fields)
        {

COleVariant VOptional((long)DISP_E_PARAMNOTFOUND, VT_ERROR);    


            if( !objApp.CreateDispatch("Excel.Application") ){AfxMessageBox("XLS ERROR");   return FALSE;}
            objApp.SetVisible(TRUE);
            objApp.SetUserControl(TRUE);
            lpDisp = objApp.GetWorkbooks();
            objBooks.AttachDispatch(lpDisp);

               lpDisp = objBooks.Open(destFileName, VOptional, VOptional, VOptional,VOptional, VOptional, VOptional, VOptional, VOptional, VOptional, VOptional, VOptional, VOptional);
               lpDisp2 = lpDisp;
               objBook.AttachDispatch(lpDisp);
               lpDisp = objBook.GetSheets();
               objSheets.AttachDispatch(lpDisp);

        if(time == 2)
        {
               if( blNewXls )
                   objBook.SaveAs(COleVariant(destFileName),VOptional, VOptional, VOptional, VOptional,VOptional, FALSE, VOptional, VOptional,VOptional, VOptional);            
               else
                   objBook.Save();

               objBooks.Close();
               objApp.Quit();       

               objBooks.ReleaseDispatch();  // Release the object-IDispatch binding.
               objApp.ReleaseDispatch();
               objBooks = NULL;  // Destroy the object references.
               objApp = NULL;
                   time = 1;
        }
        else
           time = 2 ;

               return TRUE;
        }
```

expected result : write 2 times
actual result : access violation when open() function executes

Answer (score 1):

This is not an MFC question. Really, it is an Excel OLE automation question.

Why are you making it visible and why are you calling SetUserControl(TRUE)? Neither of those things should be necessary. For some reason, it is likely hanging onto a reference and not closing Excel because you made those calls you did which are not necessary.

After you call the first time, is there still a reference to Excel running in the background? Check task manager to verify that is it running or closed.

It seems obvious to me that it is still open. If it is open, you can't open it again.

Answer (score 0):

A good news for you is that a csv file doesn't require Excel OLE, you can handle this using MFC only ... there is no need to have Excel/Office installed ... handle your csv file as text file using CStdioFile: [CStdioFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cstdiofile-class?view=vs-2017)